# Please ID this grass, shrub or willow in Highlands County Florida

Tags: identification, trees, leaves, shrubs, sand

Can somebody help me identify this species. It grows in clusters like a grass, the stock gets to about inch thick and grows straight and solid.  Also like a basket willow. But also wondering if this is Cutthroat seep?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

some of these taken at different times of the year. In some cases I'm not sure if I am looking at the same species or not. Like this I'm not sure about:   [image]

Comment: Can you provide a close-up, non-blurry photo of the leaves?

Comment: Im 300 miles away and going through random pics. Wont be back for another 2 weeks.  Added another pic and will look for others.  Thanks.  I am wondering if maybe this is Cutthroat Seep Grass?

Comment: and added another.  taken over different times of the year. Not even sure I'm looking at the same species really. the last one seems to come more from a grass and never seems to get a hard stock , and the first ones seem to sprout like that from the start and develop rigid straight hard stocks.